# The same cluster in Databricks sometimes fails, sometimes works when starting

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

As mentioned in the title, I have a cluster created at my Azure Databricks account with the following characteristics:
[image]

The problem I face is, without a clear reason, that it fails when I try to start it, being forced to try for it several times, without changing anything.

Can anyone suggest where to look for any possible logs about it? The only ones I saw describe a 'nodes could not be acquired' as follows:
[image]

I think it should automatically retry until it gets started.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, **Operation is not allowed** due to **unavailability of Compute-VM (Cores-vCPUs)**.

In order to overcome this issue, I would request you to create a new support request to increase the quota limit of the Compute-VM (Cores-VCPUs) for `Standard_DS3_v2` series and the `region` which you are trying to create.

[image]

> If you want to raise the limit or quota above the default limit, [open an online customer support request at no charge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-resource-quota).

Comment: thanks for your answer, nevertheless, the problem is not being able to use the cluster, but the fact that it works after several trials (i.e., I end up using it everyday, but trying for several times)